# Google Cloud DNS Services - entity.change parameter is required but missing

Tags: php, dns, google-cloud-platform, google-api-client, google-cloud-dns

With the following code using Google's PHP API Client I am receiving this response.

> Google_Service_Exception with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/PROJECT-NAME/managedZones/DNSZONE/changes: (400) The 'entity.change' parameter is required but was missing.

Where PROJECT-NAME and DNSZONE are my project and zone.

```
$client_email = MYCLIENT;
$private_key = file_get_contents('config/credentials/KEY.p12');
$scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ndev.clouddns.readwrite');
$project = "PROJECT-NAME";
$managedZone = "DNSZONE";

$creds = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($client_email,$scopes,$private_key);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($creds);

$resource = new Google_Service_Dns_ResourceRecordSet();
$resource->kind = "dns#resourceRecordSet";
$resource->name = "testing.DNSZONE.net.";
$resource->rrdatas[] = "testing.otherhost.com.";
$resource->ttl = 800;
$resource->type = "CNAME";

$dns = new Google_Service_Dns($client);
$change = new Google_Service_Dns_Change();
$change->kind = "dns#change";
$change->setAdditions($resource);

$dns->changes->create($project,$managedZone,$change);
```

I am a bit confused as to how to set this parameter.  Or where I am even am to define it.

Comment: I figured it out - after 6 hours of fighting this - I realized that I needed to wrap my additions in an array.  The error message was arcane and unhelpful.

Comment: Is the rrdatas[ ] array that was throwing the error?

Comment: I needed to wrap my Google_Service_Dns_ResourceRecordSets in an array.  I'll revise and an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for clarify what the answer is, setAdditions expects an array.

```
$change->setAdditions([ $resource ]);
```